# average two column by select where select

Tags: sql

I tried to create average of range and it didn't work

```
SELECT AVG(XXX) 
WHERE (SELECT (MAX(`VALUE_`) -MIN(`VALUE_`)) AS XXX 
FROM `rs_hot_end` 
WHERE (`RESULT_ID` =1050 OR `RESULT_ID`=1051)
AND `JOB_NO`= 'BEG0999'
AND `MC_NO` = 'BP52' 
GROUP BY `TEST_DATE`,`TEST_TIME`,`JOB_NO`,`MC_NO`) ;
```

and tried this too

```
(SELECT AVG((MAX(`VALUE_`) -MIN(`VALUE_`))) AS XXX 
    FROM `rs_hot_end` 
    WHERE (`RESULT_ID` =1050 OR `RESULT_ID`=1051)
    AND `JOB_NO`= 'BEG0999'
    AND `MC_NO` = 'BP52' 
    GROUP BY `TEST_DATE`,`TEST_TIME`,`JOB_NO`,`MC_NO`)
```

Comment: Help us help you, what sort of answer are you looking for? You give us some code, and that it didn't work. We don't know what you are trying to do, nor can we see your screen (do you get an error? unexpected results? What do you expect, what do you get?). Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I need to average (max-min) in each group. in my code (SELECT (MAX(`VALUE_`) -MIN(`VALUE_`)) AS XXX 
FROM `rs_hot_end` 
WHERE (`RESULT_ID` =1050 OR `RESULT_ID`=1051)
AND `JOB_NO`= 'BEG0999'
AND `MC_NO` = 'BP52' 
GROUP BY `TEST_DATE`,`TEST_TIME`,`JOB_NO`,`MC_NO`) it worked well and how to average the column

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  That expression is really vague.  Do you get an error?  Does the query return no rows?  Are the values incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in a sub-query, then aggregate that result.

```
SELECT AVG(MaxValue - MinValue) AS AvgValueDiff
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     JOB_NO, MC_NO, TEST_DATE, TEST_TIME,
     MIN(`VALUE_`) AS MinValue,
     MAX(`VALUE_`) AS MaxValue
   FROM `rs_hot_end` 
   WHERE RESULT_ID IN (1050, 1051)
     AND JOB_NO = 'BEG0999'
     AND MC_NO = 'BP52'
   GROUP BY 
     JOB_NO, MC_NO, TEST_DATE, TEST_TIME
) q;
```